# DDD Modeling Tournament Play

Tags: c#, model, domain-driven-design

I have the need to model out a gaming tournament. The concept is there are Seasons, and each Season starts with 50 Players that are broken into 5 Divisions of 10. Each Division is a round robin tournament where everyone will have one Match (best of 3 Games) with each other and at the end, the top 10 players (based on match points) auto-advance to the playoffs.

Out of the 40 Players remaining, the top 20 players (again, based on match points) are then entered into a second single elimination tournament. The tournament has 10 initial Matches (best of 3 Games). The 10 winners then play a second Match (best of 3 Games). These 5 winners then join the initial 10 winners for the playoffs.

Now, a single (1) Player from the remaining 35 players is selected to play in the playoffs. The playoffs will have a total of 16 players who battle in a single elimination tournament to determine the champion.

Here is what I have so far, but I don't think the model fits the description above:

[image: Model]

Any help would be great!

Comment: Because of an NDA, I am not able to show all entity names as it may lead to violations. Sorry, be assured they are not relevant to the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Where's your **Domain** Model?

I see a data model - bunch of properties, bags of state.  Might as well be DB tables.  Where's the behavior?

No offense, but I'm going to suggest your focus is in the wrong place.

Comment: You are right, the dev on this project does not know UML so he used a tool he was familiar with. No offense taken.